# How to calculate mean for batch of images in Python in a non vectorized way?

Tags: python, image, numpy

In order to calculate the image mean, one can use `numpy.mean()` if I'm not mistaken.

What `mean()` does, is simply summing all elements and then dividing by the number of all elements summed. furthermore if I want to calculate mean channelwise,(each channel has its own mean calculated), and I have an input of shape: `(num_batch, num_channel, width, height)`, I'd write :

```
numpy.mean(a,axis=(0,2,3))
```

Now, I tried to code its non vectorized version but I'm not sure I'm doing everything correctly.

This is the code that is presumed to be calculating the mean channel-wise, (its output should match that of the command given above:

```
def calc_mean_classic(a):
    #sum all elements in each channel and divide by the number of elements
    batch = a.shape[0]
    channel = a.shape[1]
    width = a.shape[2]
    height = a.shape[3]

    sum = np.zeros((channel))
    for i in range(batch):
        for c in range(channel):
            for w in range(width):
                for h in range(height):
                    sum[c] += a[i,c,w,h]

    return sum, (sum/(width*height))
```

When I run my data with `numpy.mean(a,axis=(0,2,3))`, I get :

```
[ 125.30691805  122.95039414  113.86538318]
```

but when I run the function I coded, I get :

```
sum,m3 = calc_mean_classic(data_train)
print 'sum=',sum
print 'm3=',m3
print m3[0]/(32*32)
```

Output:

```
sum= [  6.41571420e+09   6.29506018e+09   5.82990762e+09]
m3= [ 6265345.90234375  6147519.70703125  5693269.15917969]
6118.50185776
```

There is an irony here, image size is `32*32` that's why I'm doing `m3[0]/(32*32)` (`sum/width*height`) to see if I can generate the `sum[0]` value! As you can see they are completely different values, while they should yield the same value!

I have no idea what's going on here.

Comment: My go to quick and dirty troubleshooting trick: add, subtract, multiply and divide your expected output vs your current output. If you get strange correlations, that's a lead.  If you'd divided your loopy output by your vectorized output, you'd get 50000, which I expect is your batch size - which would lead you to Divakar's answer below.

Comment: @DanielForsman: Thank you very much, thats a very handy tip :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sum` along those three axes and divide by the block size, which would be `width*height` i.e. `a.shape[2]*a.shape[3]` -

```
batch_mean = np.sum(a,axis=(0,2,3))/(a.shape[2]*a.shape[3])
```

With `np.mean(a,axis=(0,2,3))` you were also dividing by the number of elems along the first axis, which doesn't seem to be intended operation there, not at least with `sum/(width*height)` with your func `calc_mean_classic`.

---

Otherwise, if you meant to simulate the behavior of `np.mean(a,axis=(0,2,3))` with the loopy `calc_mean_classic`, just edit the return statement to incorporate `a.shape[0]` -

```
return sum, (sum/(width*height*a.shape[0]))
```

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me, thanks!

```
    # YOUR CODE HERE
    a = batch.asnumpy()

    #sum all elements in each channel and divide by the number of elements
    batch = a.shape[0]
    channel = a.shape[1]
    width = a.shape[2]
    height = a.shape[3]

    sum = np.zeros((channel))
    for i in range(batch):
        for c in range(channel):
            for w in range(width):
                for h in range(height):
                    sum[c] += a[i,c,w,h]

    sum = sum/(width*height*a.shape[0])

    return mx.nd.array(sum)
```